# Getting float' object is not iterable when appending csv in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to delete duplicate words in cells of a csv file using panda df.
I found some helpful codes that helped me it would read a csv and append to a new csv file.
Below is an example of the data set.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['Anakin Ana, Anakin Ana', 'Anakin Ana, Chris Cannon', 'Chris Cannon', 'Bella Bold, Chris Cannon, Bella Bold'],
                   'b': ['Bella Bold, Chris Cannon, Chris Cannon', 'Donald Deakon', 'Bella Bold, Bella Bold, ', 'Bella Bold'],
                   'c': ['Chris Cannon', 'Chris Cannon, Donald Deakon, Donald Deakon', 'Chris Cannon', 'Anakin Ana, Bella Bold, Bella Bold']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2])
```

I am trying to only delete duplicates in each cell.
There are many columns in my data but I tried just for one of the columns which is 'pub_emp_year'.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
filepath = "C:/data/Untitled Folder/creditdata.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath,encoding='utf-8')
    
for col in ["pub_emp_year"]:
    df[col]=df[col].str.split(", ").map(set).str.join(", ")

df.to_csv('creditdata2.csv',mode='a',index=False)
```

But I get a error saying

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-639c2df4be78> in <module>
      5 
      6 for col in ["pub_emp_year"]:
----> 7     df[col]=df[col].str.split(", ").map(set).str.join(", ")
      8 
      9 df.to_csv('creditdata2.csv',mode='a',index=False)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   3628         dtype: object
   3629         """
-> 3630         new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
   3631         return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
   3632 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
   1143 
   1144         # mapper is a function
-> 1145         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
   1146 
   1147         return new_values

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I found that this happens when I mismatch list and float, but not sure what I made to float cause all of my data is list.

Comment: some sample data would go a long way here.

Comment: You have missing data in your column. Missing data in pandas is represented as `NaN` which is of type float. `.map(set)` is failing because of this. You'll get the same error with just `set(np.NaN)`.

Comment: I've added an example of the data set!

Comment: Thank you Henry, I do have missing values in the data. How should I fix the code to manage the missing values?

Comment: You can remove the rows or columns with missing values; or replace the missing values with a fixed value, a value from the previous or next row, or even something calculated. There is a whole guide on that at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html .

Comment: The missing values argument doesn't make sense, since the column should have strings, as you are using `.str.split()` on it. Check the dtype of that column: it should be `str`, or `object` if there are missing values. Such missing are represented by `None` though for strings, not by `NaN`.

Comment: That is not true in `pandas` missing values are (by default) always represented by `NaN` regardless of column type. If the column does not support NaN the column type is changed so it does. The only way to get `None` in a column is for it to be explicitly placed there. (And even then sometimes it will become NaN). The small example`pd.Series(['a, b, c', np.NaN, 'd, e, f']).str.split(', ').map(set)` reproduces this error.

Comment: Like was said above, how do you want to handle missing data? What should the output contain in the case of a row containing no information? Do you want to preserve the NaN Values as NaN? Replace with empty string? etc. One approach would be to filter before processing like `df[col] = df.loc[df[col].notna(), col].str.split(", ").map(set).str.join(", ")`

Comment: Hi thank you so much Henry! I don't mind leaving the missing rows as missing or empty string as long as they don't delete or mess up the order. It seems your suggestion is working I don't have the float error anymore! I'll look at the data and get back to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Henry's help solved the problem! this worked perfectly.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
filepath = "C:/Users/Jimmy Kim/data/Untitled Folder/creditdata.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath,encoding='utf-8')
    
for col in ["pub_emp_year" ]:
    df[col] = df.loc[df[col].notna(), col].str.split(", ").map(set).str.join(", ")

df.to_csv('creditdata2.csv',mode='a',index=False)
```